# Hadoop MapReduce java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hello I'm having an issue while running a map reduce job.
Hello I'm having an issue while running a map reduce job.
Hello I'm having an issue while running a map reduce job.
Hello I'm having an issue while running a map reduce job.
Hello I'm having an issue while running a map reduce job.

It show me error as below:

[image]

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.*;

public class Covid19_1 {
    
    // 4 types declared: Type of input key, type of input value, type of output key, type of output value
    public static class MyMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private static LongWritable new_cases = new LongWritable(0);
        private Text loc = new Text();
        private String include_world;

        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,  InterruptedException{
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            include_world = conf.get("is_world");
        }
        
        // The 4 types declared here should match the types that was declared on the top
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ","); 
            String date_year="";
            // Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
            // String include_world = config.get("is_world");

            try{
                if(tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    date_year = tok.nextToken().split("-")[0];
                }
                if(tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    loc.set(tok.nextToken());
                }
                if(tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    new_cases.set(Long.parseLong(tok.nextToken()));
                }

                if(!date_year.equals("2020"))
                    return;
                if(include_world.equals("false") && (loc.toString().contains("World") || loc.toString().contains("International")))
                    return;
                context.write(loc,new_cases);
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
        
    }
    
    

    // 4 types declared: Type of input key, type of input value, type of output key, type of output value
    // The input types of reduce should match the output type of map
    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        private LongWritable total = new LongWritable();
        
        // public void setup(Context context) throws IOException,  InterruptedException{
        //  System.out.println("HELLO from setup");
        // }
        // Notice the that 2nd argument: type of the input value is an Iterable collection of objects 
        //  with the same type declared above/as the type of output value from map
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // System.out.println("HELLO");
            long sum = 0;
            for (LongWritable tmp: values) {
                sum += tmp.get();
            }
            total.set(sum);
            // This write to the final output
            context.write(key, total);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        long st  = new Date().getTime();
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("is_world",args[1]);
        Job myjob = Job.getInstance(conf, "my word count test");
        myjob.setJarByClass(Covid19_1.class);
        myjob.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        myjob.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        myjob.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        myjob.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        // Uncomment to set the number of reduce tasks
        // myjob.setNumReduceTasks(2);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(myjob, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(myjob,  new Path(args[2]));
        boolean ret = myjob.waitForCompletion(true);   
        long et = new Date().getTime();
        double est_t = (et - st)/1000.0;
        System.out.println("Time taken for task 1: " + est_t + " sec");
        System.exit(ret ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: please share your code, especially file `Covid19_1.java` line 95

Comment: Hello i added it

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hadoop documentation to run a jar file users must execute the jar file using this command:

```
hadoop jar  <yourjar>  [mainClass]  args...
```

So, you pass two parameter to your program but tried to use from 3th parameter which is `args[2]` in the following line:

```
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(myjob,  new Path(args[2]));
```

Based your command :

1. args[0] is /home/asus/input
2. args[1] is /home/asus
3. args[2] throws **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException**

`args[2]` is not defined in your input.